# Custom model binder with IDictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 REST API with a method that has two parameters:

```
public async Task<object> CreateSingleEntity([FromRoute] string entity, [FromBody] IDictionary<string, object> model)
{
    //process data
}
```

This works well when I do this request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:7299/api/data/cars' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "model": 1,
    "name": "Ford",
    "id":"a47d52de-fcd1-48e7-8656-7edb84dc78bd",
    "is_created": true,
    "date":"2022-09-23",
    "datetime":"2022-09-23 13:10"
}'
```

But because I'm using MediatR I'd like to use a model instead.

```
public class CreateSingleRecord : ICommand<object>
{
    [FromRoute(Name ="entity")]
    public string Entity { get; init; }

    [FromBody]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Record { get; init; }
}
```

sadly every time I try to replace my previous method with:

```
public async Task<object> CreateSingleEntity([FromHybrid] CreateSingleRecord model)
{
    //process data
}
```

I'm getting errors:

> {
> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
> "status": 400,
> "traceId": "00-0b9809f4e2a656dd8b0255940ce84db7-49b9b11c21ce132a-00",
> "errors": {
> "Record": [
> "The Record field is required."
> ]
> } }

I've tried using [[FromHybrid] model binder](https://github.com/billbogaiv/hybrid-model-binding) but sadly it isn't working with dictionary types.

The endpoint must handle dynamic objects because the whole system is very dynamic, so I can't bind to predefined models.

I think the only way is to create a model binder, but I have no clue how to deserialize the entire body as a dictionary and assign it to my model's property.

Comment: Your object that is sent to server has to remain the same.  You code needs to lookup the object in the dictionary by key value and only send the value and not the key.

Comment: @jdweng I think that I wasn't very clear in my question, sorry I'm not a native English speaker. I want to bind the entire body to the Record property of my model. Right now I must create my model by hand, like so: var m = new CreateSingleRecord() {Entity =entity, Record=model}. but this should be done automatically.

Comment: You have to create a request in a format that the server expects.  Your model also must meet the MediatR requirements.  You could use a JSON serializer but it probably won't meet both the MediatR and server formats.  You also have to extract the value of the dictionary by the key before creating the request.  The server does not recognize a dictionary input.

Comment: @jdweng MediatR has nothing to do with it. It works fine when I create model by hand, The reason I created this question is that I want to have a consistent API and be able to bind the entire body to the model's property.

Comment: The model must meet MediatR format and meet the json format in the html.  There is no binding that will automatically convert one format to the other.  You need to write code.

Comment: @jdweng I know that :) I just need some help with it. maybe someone did this before, I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is another way. If your problem is really just that you want to get the values of the dictionary, then just send your request like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:7299/api/data/cars' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{ "Record": {
    "model": 1,
    "name": "Ford",
    "id":"a47d52de-fcd1-48e7-8656-7edb84dc78bd",
    "is_created": true,
    "date":"2022-09-23",
    "datetime":"2022-09-23 13:10"
}}'
```

If you want to get rid of the `Record` property, then you probably cannot avoid writing a custom binder. Something like this.

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CreateSingleRecordBnder))]
public class CreateSingleRecord : ICommand<object>
{
    public string Entity { get; init; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Record { get; init; }
}
```

Model binder

```
public class CreateSingleRecordBnder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var bodyStream = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(bodyStream);
        var body = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(body);

        var model = new CreateSingleRecord
        {
            Entity = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["entity"].ToString(),
            Record = data
        };

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
    }
}
```

**Update**

What about removing the hybrid binding and trying this? Is it more suitable for you?

Endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/data/{entity}")]

public async Task<object> CreateSingleEntity([FromRoute] CreateSingleRecord model)
{
    ///
}
```

And single record

```
public class CreateSingleRecord : ICommand<object>
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "entity")]
    public string Entity { get; init; }

    [FromBody]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Record { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: I don't mind writing a custom binder, I just need some guidance with that. The sample on MS website isn't very helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe this will help you with your next steps.

Comment: I had to add `[ModelBinder(typeof(CreateSingleRecordBnder ))]` attribute to my method argument because the attribute on the model doesn't work. I'm still wondering if I can reuse the default binder somehow. I've created an issue in Hybrid Model Binder: https://github.com/billbogaiv/hybrid-model-binding/issues/64, so maybe the creator will have an idea how to reuse binders. I will have around 20 models, body will be only one of the fields, so a more generic approach would be better instead of creating 20 binders

Comment: @Misiu I posted the last update, not sure if this helps you, but tried my best

Comment: I'm checking that right now :)

Comment: I was missing the `FromRoute` attribute on the method argument, what a silly mistake! The good part is I have a working custom binder I'll be able to reuse in the future. Give me some time for more testing and I'll approve your answer or get back if I find something

Comment: I really need that FromHybrid working, because I also need to add FromHeader and FromClaim (which I added to that library). Any ideas on how to solve that? If not then I'm fine with accepting the current answer.

Comment: The `[FromHeader]` attribute also works, I tested it. With Claims, it will be more difficult. But I don't think that Claims should be part of the request model. The endpoint model (CreateSingleRecord ) should represent data from the request. It would be better to create another object and use a mapper to map Claims to it in the endpoint. But this is another story.